# How do I get an Atheros AR242 / AR542 wireless card working?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, atheros

I am brand new to ubuntu as a laptop platform. As a developer I've used it as an app server but with minimal interaction.

So, I recently took my windows laptop and installed the latest 12.04 package. Most everything works great and I'm very happy. however, the wireless is very choppy. (You can see the button that enables the wireless flash on and off.)

I have tried several steps mentioned in other posts but, being a newbie, I'm afraid I'm doing more harm than good. the information I can provide follows. any help would be greatly appreciated.

lspci

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer but it was the answer for me when I had trouble with Broadcom. I used the Synaptic tool to update wireless components and that may help. However, the actual Kernel could help most. You can use the synaptic tool to download a newer kernel by searching for linux image. Then choose the generic and the latest.

I had even recompiled the mainline kernel (from kernel.org) in order to get all of my devices to be fully supported and for the system to run super fast. That would be a part II solution and I would refer you to my blog.

[Kernel compiling on Ubuntu](http://compilethekernel.blogspot.com/2011/08/compile-linux-kernel.html)

This may seem like an over-kill answer but I've had wifi problems too on various systems and these were my fixes. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Joel. I tried updating to the latest everything (wireless components, kernal) without any luck. Being a newbie I am concerned about recompiling the kernel.